# Was there any point in Goblet of Fire film where Dumbledore becomes suspicious of Moody?

Tags: harry-potter

In the book *Goblet of Fire*, we have the following about Dumbledore suspecting Barty Crouch Jr/Mad-Eye Moody as being the baddie:

> ‘Moody,’ Harry said. He was still in a state of complete disbelief. ‘How can it have been Moody?’
>   ‘This is not Alastor Moody,’ said Dumbledore quietly. ‘You have never known Alastor Moody. The real Moody would not have removed you from my sight after what happened tonight. The moment he took you, I knew – and I followed.’
>   <sub>*Goblet of Fire* - page 590 - Bloomsbury - chapter thirty-five, *Veritaserum*</sub>

Is there *any* point in the **movie** version of *Goblet of Fire* that shows when Dumbledore becomes suspicious of Crouch Jr/Moody? I think I might have pinpointed a moment, but would like answers from the community before making a conclusion. I know it must have happened because, in the movie, Dumbledore somehow knows to follow Harry and rescue him from Crouch Jr/Moody.

**Was there any point in Goblet of Fire (MOVIE) where Dumbledore becomes suspicious of Moody?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that one of the largest (movie only) clues was at 01:36 when Mad Eye Moody does "the tongue thing" in front of his father, Barty Crouch Sr.

I think we can reasonably assume that in a world where people are able to impersonate each other with trivial ease, this sort of thing would be noticed and discussed, especially in light of the fact that Crouch Sr would know that his son had escaped.

The final straw was (as in the book) when Moody/Crouch Jr dragged Harry off. Dumbledore finally came up with "missing polyjuice ingredients + missing Crouch Jr = trouble" and decided to find Harry in a hurry.

[image]

Comment: As I recall, it wasn't Polyjuice that went missing, it was ingredients for same. And Snape didn't discuss that with Dumbledore, it was with Snape himself on the stairs.

Comment: @JohnP -- I believe in the movie Snape discussed the missing Polyjuice ingredients with Harry, and accused Harry of stealing them.

Comment: Ooo, good catch! That is *way* before I thought it would be ... Barty Crouch Jr/Mad-Eye Moody: Doing the tongue thing WAY before Miley Cyrus ;P

Comment: @Slytherincess - I searched and you are correct, it was just a generic "potion ingredients missing" when he was talking to Moody about his office break in on the stairs.

Comment: Huh? Wasn't the question about whe Dumbledore would suspect? Why would he suspect something based on Barty Crouch Sr? (who at the time, I think, was already Imperiused)

Comment: @JohnP -- I should clarify that I'm asking about the *movie* adaptation of *Goblet of Fire*, which is different from the book. The book is clear about when Dumbledore suspects Crouch Jr/Moody, but I'm wondering if there's any hint of Dumbledore suspecting Crouch Jr/Moody in the movie. :)

Comment: @DVK - They cut all of the Crouches' back story from the movie, so there is no indication that Crouch Sr was ever under the effects of the Imperius Curse. It's left as kind of a mystery why Crouch Sr was killed, IIRC. I'm not sure Crouch Jr even addresses it when he's confessing at the end. The confession in the book was quite long, but it's a few lines in the movie. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Yup. In the movie there's no real explanation of why Dumbledore came in "guns blazing", nor is there any point at which he indicates his suspicions.

Comment: @Slytherincess I always assumed that Crouch Sr was killed because he witnessed the tongue thing and so Jr realised he must be suspicious or could realise.

Comment: @dvk - Either because Crouch Sr. shared his concerns with Dumbledore or because his death roused his suspicions.

Comment: @Simon -- I'm wondering how Dumbledore would have known about the tongue thing. Crouch Jr was facing away from Dumbledore and toward his father when he first did the tongue dart. Perhaps someone told Dumbledore exactly what happened at the hearing, or Crouch Sr told him. Otherwise, I'm not sure how he would know that this was characteristic of Crouch Jr.

Comment: @Slytherincess I was merely suggesting why Sr was murdered not how Dumbledore came to know. I think Dumbledore knew something was off with Moody aka Jr but probably didn't think of it by which I mean he came to the same conclusion as everyone Moody is a bit gaga. I think it clicked after the graveyard scene where we are on the field with Harry and dead Cedric he decides to see what Moody will do with Harry (but obviously gets distracted in the chaos) so follows him onwards a bit later. Doesn't explain busting down the door as he could have easily hit harry...

Comment: @Slytherincess More to the point, how would Dumbledore know when Crouch Jr / Mad-Eye does "the tongue thing"? Harry and Crouch Sr are the only ones to see it IIRC, and Crouch Sr is killed soon after.

Comment: @randal'thor - I think it's reasonable to assume that Dumbledore and Crouch Sr. are in regular contact.

Comment: @Richard Yes, but Crouch Sr was killed on the same day he saw Moody do "the tongue thing" - why should we assume he spoke to Dumbledore in between? And if he DID speak to Dumbledore, surely Dumbledore would have taken some kind of action rather than just letting MEM/BCJ keep on doing his thing unchecked?

Comment: That said, it IS a very good catch of yours to notice this tongue thing :-) I just don't think it's a good answer to this particular question. Had the question been "were there any hints to film viewers that MEM=BCJ?", this would be an excellent answer.